# How to pass array reference from function?

Tags: c++

I want to pass value of array in function by reference

1. My first try with **variable** (it works well):

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   int input(int &);
   int main()
   {
       int a;
       input(a);
       cout << "the value : " << a << endl;
       system("pause");
       return 0;
   }

   int input(int &a)
   {
       cin >> a;   
   }
   ```
2. But when i change `a` to **`a[]`** like in the following code, it
   doesn't work

   ```
   #include <iostream.h>
   using namespace std;

   int input(int &[]);
   int main()
   {
       int a[2], i;
       input(a);
       for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
       {
           cout << a << endl;
       }

       system("pause");
       return 0;
   }

   int input(int &a[])
   {
       int i;
       for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
       {
           cin >> a[i];
       }  
   }
   ```

Comment: At least the array parameter in the function declaration must match the exact length of what's passed to it: `int input(int &a[2])`, you are trying to pass two parameters, where only one was declared: `input(a, 2);`

Comment: You have to call your method as `input(a)` in the second case

Comment: You should say what "not working" means - did you get a compiler error?  runtime error?  Crash?  Looks to me like you should get a compiler error.

Comment: You should strongly consider using `std::vector` instead. Much easier to use and no need to worry about size.

Comment: yes arrays of references are illegal

Answer (score 2):

This record

```
int &[]
```

denotes an array of references that is forbided in C++.

Declare the function the following way

void input( int ( & )[2] );

Also you are using invalid range of indeces. The valid range is [0, 1]. So the function will look as

```
void input( int ( &a )[2] );
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i]; 
}
```

Also you could define the function the following way

```
void input( int a[], size_t n );
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i]; 
}
```

and call it as

```
input( a, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
void input(int (&a)[2]);
```

or simply

```
void input(int (&)[2]);
```

But in function definition, you need also to give the array name:

```
void input(int (&a)[2]) {...}
```

You need to use `(&array)` to clarify to the compiler that you want a reference to an array, rather than the (invalid) array of references `int &array[2];`.

And call it like this:

```
input(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for returning and taking array references is:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T(&do_nothing(T(&arg)[N]))[N]
{
    return arg;
}
```

Or, more simply with a templated type alias:

```
template<typename T, size_t N> using arrayref = T(&)[N];

template<typename T, size_t N>
arrayref<T, N> do_nothing(arrayref<T, N> arg)
{
    return arg;
}
```

When you have defined the previous type alias template, it becomes very simple to work with array references, e.g. This is how you would declare a function that takes a reference to an array of two integers:

```
void give_me_two_ints(arrayref<int, 2> two_ints);
```

To be used like:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
for(auto const& i : do_nothing(a)) std::cout << i << "\n";
```